# Azure kubernetes - Grafana authentication

Tags: azure, kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, azure-aks

I am planning to deploy 15 different applications in azure kubernetes and would be using Prometheus and Grafana for monitoring.

I have deployed both the Prometheus and Grafana on a separate namespace on the dedicated node.

As Grafana does not supported authentication, how can I secure the Grafana website with Azure AD authentication. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 6.7 and newer of Grafana you can configure Azure AD as OAuth2 provider. (For reference: https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/auth/azuread/)

Also you can use Azure AD Domain Services (AD DS) to enable  LDAP(S) on top of Azure AD and LDAP is a supported authentication mechanism for Grafana.

For reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview#azure-ad-ds-features